# Double click on Matlab file opens a new session, even if one is already running

Tags: matlab, thunar

As said, if I double-click a file that Thunar recognizes as a "Matlab script/function", a new session of Matlab launches. This happens even when I already have a Matlab session running. How can I make Thunar to recognize the Matlab instance already running? Note that other file types do not have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't Thunar or a file manager, the problem is MatLab. If there is no option in MatLab to start only one instance, you can do nothing except writing a feature request for MatLab.